# JavaScript Generators - How to skip yield when called using .next() ?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, yield

JavaScript generators allow you to yield actions in a procedural manner.

Is it possible to skip/invoke specific yields natively?

Given the below example, how could this be achieved?

I would like to yield values 1, 3 & 5.

```js
function *getVal() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
    yield 4;
    yield 5;
} 


let x = getVal();

// I want to yield ONLY values 1 , 3 , & 5

// Here val will equal 1
let val = x.next();

// I now want to val to equal 3
val = << skip second yield and hit 3 >>

// Is it possible to skip a yield natively?
// ...
```

Comment: If you want to skip one yield, why not just call `x.next()` before assigning `x.next()` to `val`?

Comment: You can't skip a yield, but you can call it and ignore the result.

Comment: @Ivan  Thank you, I'm aware you can just call without assigning, but how about skipping without having to invoke the one that is going to be skipped.

Comment: @Nicholas, this assumes you know the value that will be yielded by the generator, right?

Comment: @Ivan Not necessarily. I really just want to know if you can call a specific yield, based on their order. Assuming I know there are 5 yields, I just want to skip 2 and 4 all together.

Comment: I think the thing to keep in mind is that a generator still behaves like a function. A `yield` pauses the function until it starts again, but you can't skip part of a generator from outside any more than you can reach in and skip part of any other function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generators follow the javascript [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), so there aren't many options to control them beyond calling `next()`.

But, since you are in control of the logic of the generator, you can define the behavior you want for each of those calls to `next()`. If you want to skip numbers, just make a way to communicate that to the generator.

For example, this generator will make consecutive numbers, but skip based on the number passed into `next()`

```js
function *getVal() {
    let n = 1;
    let skip = 0
    while (n <= 15){
        skip =  yield n
        n = n+1+ (skip || 0)
    }
} 


let x = getVal();

console.log(x.next().value);  // start with 1
console.log(x.next(1).value); // skip two
console.log(x.next().value)
console.log(x.next(2).value)  // skip 5 and 6
console.log(x.next(1).value); // skip 8
//etc.
```

Comment: So you're saying there are no native JavaScript hooks to skip yields? This is a cool approach.

Comment: @Nicholas not that I know of — the iterator protocol is pretty simple, you basically have `next()` at your disposal.

Comment: Thank you Mark, if you could include in your answer that there is no native way to skip yields I'll be inclined to accept this answer as a workaround.

Comment: Caveat with this being that the first call to `next` can't skip anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can always call the next value without assigning it, then call `.next` again and assign it:

```js
function *getVal() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
    yield 4;
    yield 5;
} 


let x = getVal();

let val = x.next().value;   // 1
console.log(val);           

x.next();
val = x.next().value;       // 3
console.log(val);

x.next();
val = x.next().value;       // 5
console.log(val);
```

This way you are *ignoring* some of the yielded values.